# How to pass values to a trained Regressor Function from a Javascript front end?

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I trained a SGDRegressor on a dataset with 3756 rows. This returned an alpha value that I want to use. Now I want to output the prediction based on the new set of values received from the Javascript front end. This includes categorical data that would need one hot encoding. I want to know how to pass the values to the trained regressor module and generate a prediction based on it.

```
def rmse_cv(model):
    rmse = np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, X_train, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=5))
    return(rmse)


alphas = [0.00005, 0.00015, 0.00045, 0.0135]
mv_sgd = [rmse_cv(SGDRegressor(alpha = alpha)).mean() 
        for alpha in alphas]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you use the .fit() and .predict() methods, assuming you're using sklearn. Create a predictor object like this:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

clf = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Then when you get a new value, say from javascript, you use the predict.method

```
prediction = clf.predict(newCase)
```

There are many ways to get a value from javascript, as mentioned, django may be a good start.

Comment: Do I pass the alpha I got from my function above to the regressor in variable clf, then encode the new categorical inputs and pass them as an array to predict()?

Comment: you don't manually create the alpha - use sklearn . the SGDRegressor object will have the coefficients stored within it, then to use them just use the .predict() method

Comment: What order should the arguments be passed in?

Comment: The size of X and the size of the passed data frame is different. How does one deal with that?

Comment: The order you can find in the documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html

the size (number of features) should be the same for both.